# Swift - efficiently query one array of Integers based on another Array called queries which has Indexes of the first array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I want to efficiently query one array of Integers based on another Array called queries which has Indexes of the first array.

```
let arrayWithData = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35, 56]
let queries = [2, 4, 6]
```

the new array should return:

```
let queriedArray = [30, 25, 56]
```

Explanation:

**30 is index 2 of arrayWithData**

**25 is index 4 of arrayWithData**

**56 is index 6 of arrayWithData**

How can this be achieved quickly and efficiently without using loops. Perhaps using map or filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = queries.compactMap { $0 < arrayWithData.count ?  arrayWithData[$0] : nil  }
```

in case you're 100% sure queries indices will be with in count of array do

```
let res = queries.map{ arrayWithData[$0]}
```

Comment: endIndex will be slightly more efficient than count:  O(1) rather than O(n)  `let res = queries.compactMap { $0 < arrayWithData.endIndex ? "\(arrayWithData[$0]) is index \($0) of arrayWithData " : nil  }`

Comment: `{ arrayWithData.indices ~= $0 ? arrayWithData[$0] : nil }` would work with array slices as well

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrayWithData = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35, 56]
let queries = [2, 4, 6]

let queriedArray = queries.map({arrayWithData[$0]}) // Your desired output
```